# Export data to same CSV file for multiple runs of .m file

Tags: matlab, csv

I am running a MATLAB program and storing the results in two matrices. For each run of the program, those matrices are written to the same .csv file.

How can I continue to store data to the same file for future runs of the program? Is there a function that checks for data already being present to avoid overwriting cells?

```
t = 0.0001*[0:70];

v = B_2*R_R.*exp(-alpha.*t).*sin(omega_d.*t);

tv = [t; v].';

csvwrite('thedata.csv',tv,3,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't resist rewriting your code a bit.

This should be equivalent to what you have, and print both vectors to `thedata.csv`.

```
t = 0.0001*[0:70];
v = B_2*R_R.*exp(-alpha.*t).*sin(omega_d.*t);

tv = [t; v].';

csvwrite('thedata.csv',tv,3,0)
```

Due to the way csv-files are stored, you can only append data at the end of the file, which happens to be the bottom row, not the last column. What you *should* do, is concatenate all data *before* writing to the csv-file. That way you avoid multiple calls to `csvwrite` or `dlmwrite` (they are time consuming).

If that's impossible, then I suggest reading the data from the csv-file, using csvread, append the new data to the data you retrieve, and write it all back again.

```
csvwrite('thedata.csv',tv)
mydata = csvread('thedata.csv');
mydata2 = [mydata, tv2];
csvwrite('thedata.csv',mydata2)
```